# Why does someNumber = rand() & 100 + 1; not produce an error?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, srand, addressof

I was attempting to generate a random number between (1 - 100), and the code to ran, but not doing what I wanted. I noticed I accidentally type **&**, instead of **%** with the rand() function, and the compiler did **NOT** give me an error. What exactly is going on? Why was no error generated? Is the **&** returning an address? This bug was tricky to find because it's a simple typo that's easy to miss.

Here is the typo:

```
unsigned int randomNumber = rand() & 100 + 1;
```

But this is what I mean to type:

```
unsigned int randomNumber = rand() % 100 + 1;
```

Here is the code using **rand() with &** in case you wish to run it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(nullptr)));
    unsigned int randomNumber;
    char again;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Do you want to generate a random number? (y/n) ";
        std::cin >> again;
        randomNumber = rand() & 100 + 1;
        std::cout << randomNumber << '\n';
    } while (again == 'y');


    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: You can do this more directly with [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) from the random library. See the example at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

It's the [bitwise and operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic_operators). It takes two numbers, then it "ands" their bits.

For example: `3 & 10` is `2`.

```
 0011
&1010
 ----
 0010
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I guess the follow up question would be, when _in a real world situation_ would I ever need to produce a random number to manipulate its bits? I thought that when dealing with bits, you wanted precise control and not randomness.

Comment: Imagine you have a `enum Features {FOO = 1 << 0, BAR = 1 << 1,  BAZ = 1 << 2, BANG = 1 << 3 };` and a `void DoThing(int feature_flags)` -- and you want to call `DoThing` with a random set of features. Then you'd be able to call `DoThing(rand() & 0xF)`, to get your feature. Either way, the compiler can't know what you're using the bits for. `rand()` returns a numeric type, not a "don't-use-me-for-bitwise-operations" numeric type.

Answer (score 1):

There's no error because it's a perfectly legal expression. The result of the call to `rand()` is *bitwise-and*ed with the result of `100 + 1`.